# Badge Hammer UI Bug?

Tags: bug, design

[image: Badge Hammer Screenshot]

What gives with the white box between the words "close" and "questions"?

Example taken from: [Get back default implementation of window.Map in Visualforce page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/124472/get-back-default-implementation-of-window-map-in-visualforce-page)

Comment: I'm curious where you're seeing that? There are only 2 users with a Gold badge for visualforce, sfdcfox and keithc. You've got quite a ways to go to get the Gold badge since you're still working on the Silver one.